# Testing ProcessStartInfo processes execution

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, nunit

Let's assume I have some method that executes CLI application. For example:

```
public string SomeMethod(string cmd)
{
    var p = new ProcessStartInfo(cmd);
    // processing execution results
    return result;
}
```

How can I change this method to make it testable?

I see that I can split that method into 2:
1. Executes CLI app and passes the execution result to the second
2. Processes the results in some way and returns the answer

May be some other handy ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've decided to implement that as i offered in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I fully understand what you are doing but it you could intercept STDOUT and STDERR of the process.  However, this does require setting the `UseShellExecute`, `RedirectStandardError`, and `RedirectStandardOut` flags on the `ProcessStartInfo' instance to true.